# Simple intuitions and proofs on $SU(k)$ outer automorphism without Dynkin diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-group

How to show that the $SU(2)$ has no outer automorphism, while the $SU(k)$ with $k>2$ has an outer automorphism $\mathbf{Z}/2$?

I understand some would say to look at the Dynkin diagram. But this is not very transparent and intuitive enough.

Are there other smart ways?

For example, I know that we can regard outer automorphism of $SU(k)$ as complex conjugation:
$$
g \in SU(k) \mapsto g^* \in SU(k).$$
So we need to show whether it is possible to find conjugation action of $x$ on $g$
$$
g \mapsto x g x^{-1}
$$
such that
$$
x g x^{-1} = g^*.
$$

If we prove that is possible with $k=2$ then $SU(2)$ has no outer automorphism If we  prove that is impossible, while the $SU(k)$ with $k>2$, then it has an outer automorphism $\mathbf{Z}/2$.

Comment: Hint:  Look at eigenvalues

Comment: thanks! I saw $\pm 1$ for the $SU(2)$, and more complicated fractional eigenvalues (other than $\pm 1$) for the $SU(k)$ for $k>2$, so?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Let me give a further hint:  how do the eigenvalues of $g$ and $g^\ast$ relate?  How do the eigenvalues of conjugates relate?  Can you find a matrix in $SU(k)$ for $k\geq 3$ for which these relationships don't agree?  What goes wrong with this argument when $k=2$?

Comment: Should I look at the eigenvalues of Lie group element $g$? or the eigenvalues of Lie algebra generators?

Comment: Lie group - since you're writing $SU(k)$, I assumed you meant the group.

Comment: Their determinant is +1 since they are special () So the product of eigenvalues are +1. It seems that when (), there could be pairs of eigenvalues, complex conjugate with each other

Comment: what else could we say? thanks!